# Adding image in to 'ui-dialog-buttonpane'

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and html and I'm working on a popup dialog. I need to add an image in to 'ui-dialog-buttonpane'. There are already two buttons in that section.
Is it possible?
I tried following code but didn't get the result.

```
jQuery(".ui-dialog-buttonpane").append("<img src=' + image+ '>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after I added a time out.

```
jQuery("#ow-logindiv").dialog({
                      open: function(event, ui) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                          jQuery('#ow-logindiv').parent('div').children('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').append('<img src="' + image+ '" width="150px" >');
                        }, 0);

                      }
                    });
```